# Is there a way I can use a Virtual Machine (alternately Windows itself) to use an .iso file as a writable medium?

Tags: virtualization, dvd, iso-image, cd

I have a very specific need. I will have an exam in a couple months and I have absolutely no training in how to burn disks. I had a PC that could do this several years ago but that one's long gone, and with no drive that could burn a CD/DVD and no will to buy one to burn something on two disks, I wanted to virtualize the whole thing.

However, I do not know how to go about doing this. Usually an .iso doesn't act as a writable medium, could  I even use it as one?

And if you cannot use an .iso file as a writable medium, is there any other way for me to virtualize the disk-burning process?

Edit: I should've checked this earlier, my old laptop has a disk drive with a burner. I just network-shared it over to my PC using some weird program and it appears to be recognized as a CD/DVD burner by W10.

Comment: You are aware that Windows 10 has the ability to burn .ISO files, the only requirement, is you actually have the hardware required to do so.  I mention that fact, because for some odd reason, most devices do not even have an optical device anymore.  What you want cannot be virtualized.  The built-in feature of Windows is a two step process.  Put optical media into the drive and right click on the ISO, entire process, is also documented by Microsoft

Comment: .ISO files mounted within Windows are read-only

Comment: "no drive that could burn a CD/DVD and no will to buy one to burn something on two disks"  <-- You can do this with a USB CD Writer.  These are inexpensive to obtain.

Comment: I am aware that Windows 10 has the ability to burn ISO's, but I am not interested in that. I do not have the hardware required and I do not want to buy it, therefore I'm looking for a virtualized option that skips physical media entirely, if one is available.

I want a file to act as a CD/DVD, not to burn a file on a CD/DVD.

An USB CD Writer is still ~25$ I don't really need to spend. Of course it's not a great expense, but if I can virtualize my task I would very much like to.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with a CD/DVD burning tool such free [AnyBurn](https://www.anyburn.com/).

- Open the .iso in AnyBurn.
- Add files.
- Save the resultant .iso image.

[image: AnyBurn adding file to .iso image]

Comment: I noticed AnyBurn when I was searching, but it is an external program.
I have to know how to burn disks using Windows 10 only, no external help from burner programs :/

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the ISO as an install medium, and install to a partition in your virtual machine. I would suggest looking at the documentation for your VM. 
In Windows you can just move the file into a directory, right click (context menu), and then select "Burn Image" (Works on USB flash drives).